# TypeOf and Assertion

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, assertion, typeof

```
let message3;
console.log(typeof((<string>message3)));  //Output case1: undefined
console.log(typeof((message3 as string)));//Output case2: undefined
console.log(typeof((message3 as "ABC"))); //Output case3: undefined
console.log(typeof((message3 = "ABC")));  //Output case4: string
```

In above case why case 1-3 didn't work and gave output as string like case4.

Question 1: why case 1-3 shows "undefined"?

Question 2: what changes can be done in case 1-3 to have output "string"?

Comment: console.log(typeof 42); // expected output: "number" [MDM typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript types are erased at runtime, as well as all type assertions; they are only used by compiler to prove your code to be correct. In the transpiled JavaScript first three cases will look the same:

```
console.log(typeof(message3));
```

and `typeof(message3)` is undefined, because... well, you hasn't defined it to be anything, just as it would be in pure JS: it doesn't know about types of *variables*, all what matters is type of *value* inside it, and the value is `undefined`.

Comment: That answer Question 1. for Question 2 - any possibility to make it string at run time using assertion?

Comment: Well, for Question 2 as it was asked for now the answer is "nothing could be done". What are you trying to achieve this way?